# Finding my VM public IP address, behind a NAT

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ip, nat

I have a NAT.
My public IP address is `79.30.22.215`.
My NAT range is `192.168.1.x/24`.
My guest machine IP address is `192.168.1.3`.

So here is what I don't understand: if I run `ipconfig` from my `Windows` host machine, it says that my VM NIC has `192.168.56.1` as IP address - that is *out* of the range of my NAT.

```
Scheda Ethernet VirtualBox Host-Only Network:
Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione:
Indirizzo IPv6 locale rispetto al collegamento . : fe80::421:3d14:c4ce:8fe2%23
Indirizzo IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
Subnet mask . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Gateway predefinito . . . . . . . . . :
```

But when I run `ifconfig` from my VM:

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feb1:29e6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:b1:29:e6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 141  bytes 61843 (60.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 252  bytes 33249 (32.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 214  bytes 17108 (16.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 214  bytes 17108 (16.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

So my question is: if I have to connect to my VM machine from a remote host, what IP address should I use?

Comment: It would be 10.0.2.15, but you can't connect to NATed VM. You have to you use hostonly network, and your vm will get a 192.168.56.x ip.

Comment: A host-only network by definition can only be accessed by the host (and other guests). Nothing external.  Change it to bridged so it can get an IP on your LAN range.

Comment: Are you sure that Windows machine is a guest and not the host? The 192.168.56.x range is the default for the host-only network in VirtualBox. That 10.0.0.0/24 address was/is probably part of the internal VirtualBox NAT for your regular network. As such the answer would've been to use the "public" IP of the host and configure it accordingly to forward traffic. Using a bridged network you kind of "put it on the same" network as the host.

Comment: @Seth the running VM is Linux, the guest -that hosts the VM, I am wrong?- it's Windows. However, the bridge solution proved to work well for what I needed.

Comment: If it comes to virtualization you generally have a base OS which is your host. In your case that would probably Windows (It's the "physical" machine). On that platform you're running your virtualization solution (say VirtualBox) which creates/provides the actual VMs (which are called Guests, in your case Linux).

Comment: Then I always confused guest with host. lol. thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Please don't [edit] your question to include the answer, answer your own question. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED :**
So now I changed, as suggestion from @Paul, my VM network settings from `NAT interface` to `bridged interface`, and running `ifconfig` from the VM I obtain the following:

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feb1:29e6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:b1:29:e6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 15  bytes 2602 (2.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 180  bytes 28135 (27.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 167  bytes 14439 (14.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 167  bytes 14439 (14.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Now all works as expected. Thanks.